# Error with Blockchain Test-Driven Development

Tags: javascript, node.js, blockchain

I am currently learning how to develop blockchain using Javascript and Node.js. I am using a test-driven development format which so far has been very helpful.  Unfortunately, however, , one of my tests continuously fails and I am unable to pinpoint why. Here are three snippets of code to which this error pertains to; each of them are a different file. For clarification, the first snippet is block.js, the second is block.test.js, and the third is config.js. Also, the cryptoHash function (defined in another file) is the function used to create a SHA-256 hash with the given information.

```js
const {GENESIS_DATA, MINE_RATE} = require("./config");
const cryptoHash = require("./crypto-hash");

class Block {
    constructor({timestamp, lastHash, hash, data, nonce, difficulty}) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
        this.lastHash = lastHash;
        this.hash = hash;
        this.data = data;
        this.nonce = nonce;
        this.difficulty = difficulty;
    }

    static genesis() {
        return new this(GENESIS_DATA);
    }

    static mineBlock({lastBlock,data}) {
        let hash, timestamp;
        const lastHash = lastBlock.hash;
        let {difficulty} = lastBlock;
        let {nonce} = 0;

        do {
            nonce ++;
            timestamp = Date.now();
            hash = cryptoHash(timestamp, lastHash, data, nonce, difficulty);
        } while (hash.substring(0, difficulty) !== '0'.repeat(difficulty));

        return new this({
            timestamp,
            lastHash,
            data,
            difficulty, 
            nonce,
            hash
        });
    }  

    static adjustDifficulty({originalBlock, timestamp}) {
        
        const {difficulty} = originalBlock;

        if ((timestamp - originalBlock.timestamp) > MINE_RATE) return difficulty - 1;

        return difficulty + 1;
    }
} 

module.exports = Block;
```

```js
const Block = require('./block');
const { GENESIS_DATA, MINE_RATE } = require('./config');
const cryptoHash = require('./crypto-hash');
 
describe('Block', () => {
    const timestamp = '2000';
    const lastHash = 'foo-hash';
    const hash = 'bar-hash';
    const data = ['blockchain', 'data'];
    const nonce = 1;
    const difficulty = 1;
    const block = new Block ({timestamp, lastHash, hash, data, nonce, difficulty});
 
    it('has a timestamp, lastHash, hash, data property', () => {
        expect(block.timestamp).toEqual(timestamp);
        expect(block.lastHash).toEqual(lastHash);
        expect(block.hash).toEqual(hash);
        expect(block.data).toEqual(data);
        expect(block.nonce).toEqual(nonce);
        expect(block.difficulty).toEqual(difficulty);
    });
 
    describe('genesis()', () => {
        const genesisBlock = Block.genesis();
 
        it('returns a Block instance', () => {
            expect(genesisBlock instanceof Block).toBe(true);
        });
 
        it('returns the genesis data', () => {
            expect(genesisBlock).toEqual(GENESIS_DATA);
        });
    });
 
    describe('mineBlock()', () => {
        const lastBlock = Block.genesis();
        const data = 'mined data';
        const minedBlock = Block.mineBlock({ lastBlock, data });
 
        it('returns a Block instance', () => {
            expect(minedBlock instanceof Block).toBe(true);
        });
 
        it('sets the `lastHash` to be the `hash` of the lastBlock', () => {
            expect(minedBlock.lastHash).toEqual(lastBlock.hash);
        });
 
        it('sets the `data`', () => {
            expect(minedBlock.data).toEqual(data);
        });
 
        it('sets a `timestamp`', () => {
            expect(minedBlock.timestamp).not.toEqual(undefined);
        });

        it('creates a SHA-256 `hash` based on the proper inputs', () => {
            expect(minedBlock.hash).toEqual(
                cryptoHash(
                    minedBlock.timestamp,
                    minedBlock.nonce,
                    minedBlock.difficulty,
                    lastBlock.hash,
                    data
                )
            );
        }); 

        it('sets a `hash` that matches the difficulty criteria', () => {
            expect(minedBlock.hash.substring(0, minedBlock.difficulty))
                .toEqual('0'.repeat(minedBlock.difficulty));
        });
    });

    describe('adjustDifficulty()', () => {
        it('raises the difficulty for a quickly mined block', () => {
          expect(Block.adjustDifficulty({
            originalBlock: block, timestamp: block.timestamp + MINE_RATE - 100
          })).toEqual(block.difficulty+1);
        });
    
        it('lowers the difficulty for a slowly mined block', () => {
          expect(Block.adjustDifficulty({
            originalBlock: block, timestamp: block.timestamp + MINE_RATE + 100
          })).toEqual(block.difficulty-1);
        });
    });
});
```

```js
const MINE_RATE = 1000;
const INITIAL_DIFFICULTY = 1;

const GENESIS_DATA = {
  timestamp: 1,
  lastHash: '-----',
  hash: 'hash-one',
  difficulty: INITIAL_DIFFICULTY,
  nonce: 0,
  data: []
};

module.exports = {
  GENESIS_DATA,
  MINE_RATE,
};
```

And the error says this:

● Block › adjustDifficulty() › raises the difficulty for a quickly mined block

```
expect(received).toEqual(expected)

Expected value to equal:
  2
Received:
  0

  76 |           expect(Block.adjustDifficulty({
  77 |             originalBlock: block, timestamp: block.timestamp + MINE_RATE - 100
> 78 |           })).toEqual(block.difficulty+1);
     |               ^
  79 |         });
  80 |     
  81 |         it('lowers the difficulty for a slowly mined block', () => {

  at Object.<anonymous> (block.test.js:78:15)
```

I know this is a lot but if anyone could help me out that would be much appreciated - thanks!

Comment: As a sidenote, always try to structure your tests so that you can easily see which scenario is broken. In this case, it's actually more-or-less obvious, as `block` variable is only used in two test suites, but it's not really clear why those suites are separated by tests for other block values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line...

```
const timestamp = '2000'; // why so stringious?
```

... seems to be the root of all evil. See, when you create your testing `block`, its timestamp prop ends up being a string, not a number. So this expression...

```
timestamp: block.timestamp + MINE_RATE - 100
```

... gives you not `2900` (2000 + 1000 - 100), but `20000900` (`'20001000' - 100`) instead. You can easily check this by adding some kind of intermediate logging.

The same, of course, happens in your other test, and the ending timestamp is even higher (as both `+` are treated as concat op). But as the string stored there eventually gets cast to number (albeit quite a big one) by `-` operation, the `lowers the difficulty` test passes just fine.

So, the immediate remedy seems to be rather simple: drop those quotes and try again. Still, I'd recommend at least considering going the TypeScript way - in the long run, the benefits might outweigh the cons.